# How to update the value of an item in a database, using mysql

Tags: sql

I am lost on where to go next, I have a database that stores, name, email, uname, password, calories. I want to update the value of the calories column based on what the username is. When a new account is created the value of calories is set to default..

Here is my code I have made a start. I have made a class called database  which stores all of my database functions..
The code:

```
 SQLiteDatabase db;

  public void 
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


    String query = "update tbltest set calories= "+c.getCalories()+" where uname= "+ c.getUname();






    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);;

}
```

Offer any help on how i can approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this...

```
public void insertCalories(Intents c)
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("calories", c.getCalories);
    String selection = "where uname = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{c.getUname()};

    int result = db.update(
         "tbltest",
         values,
         selection,
         selectionArgs);

}
```

if result>0, then update is successful.

Comment: you can use Cursor c = db.query("tbltest", null, "uname = ?", null, null, null, null); and then use the cursor to get the row.

Comment: you can try like this....
if(c.getCount() > 0) {
            while(c.moveToNext()){
String calory = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("calories"));
//add this value to a list
}
           // return the list;
        }

Comment: See here... https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow

Answer (score 0):

Put the values in the `Contentvalues`, you already created.

```
values.put (columnname, value);
```

then update the Database with the method `update` like this:

```
db.update ("tbltest", values, "WHERE uname = ?", new String []{c.getUname ()});
```

P.s. You should pass the constructor of `Contentvalues` the amount of values you want to update